# Using the same Entity Framework model for EF and EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class library that has an Entity Framework ADO.NET model, and I have a .NET 7 app and a .NET Framework 4.8 app. The .NET 7 app uses Entity Framework Core and the .NET Framework app uses normal Entity Framework. Is it possible to use EF Core when the .NET 7 app is the one using the library and EF when it's 4.8?

**Note**: normal EF works on both when running normally, but when I try to publish the .NET 7 app using `dotnet publish`, I get an error that `DbSet` and such don't exist.

I tried using

```
#if NET
using EntityFrameworkCore;
#else
using System.Data.Entity;
#endif
```

but it doesn't seem to work, same issue.

Comment: _"is it possible to be able to use EFCore when the NET 7 app is the one using the library and EF when it's 4.8?"_ - **No**, it is not. EF Core and EF are very, very different despite sharing a _roughly similar_ (but far from identical) overall API design (`DbContext`, `DbSet<T>`, etc) . EF6 always uses an internal EDMX (even in code-first projects), while EFCore does away with it entirely.

Comment: I see, any idea why I can use EF in runtime but when I try to `dotnet publish` the app I get the `DbSet<> couldn't be found` error?

Comment: I don't. You haven't posted enough code to allow anyone to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Posting the entire ADO.NET Model would be pointless, as it is just generated that is why I haven't posted any code. There's virtually no code only a model that is accessed from a .NET 7 application and a .NET 4.8 application, and they both work fine but the publish doesn't.